# onrender vs init in Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I recently started trying out [Ractive.js](http://www.ractivejs.org/). I was particularly interested in its **components**. One of the things I noticed immediately is that many of the examples are using the `init` option. However when I try to use the `init` in my code I get a deprecation notice and it then recommends using `onrender` instead. `onrender` however had far fewer examples than `init` and some of the functions such as `this.find` weren't available inside `onrender`. I looked through the Github issues but couldn't find any reasoning behind this change or what the suggested path forward for selecting elements specific to a component was.

I created a [test pen](http://codepen.io/webdesserts/pen/gbNwbe?editors=101) to try creating a recursive component with the new API but I had to resort to using jQuery and an undocumented `fragment` api to select specific DOM nodes I needed to manipulate. I feel this is against how Ractive expects you to do things, but I couldn't figure out what was expected of me with the existing documentation.

What's the major differences between the `init` and `onrender` options and how does `onrender` expect you to handle manipulating specific elements and their events within a component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `this.find()` inside `onrender` (if you can't for some reason, you've found a bug!).

We split `init` into `oninit` and `onrender` a while back for a number of reasons. Those examples you mention are out of date - are they somewhere on ractivejs.org? If so we should fix them. You can find more information about lifecycle events [here on the docs](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/lifecycle-events), but the basic difference is this:

- `init` was called on initial render (assuming the component *was* rendered, i.e. never in node.js, if you were doing server-side rendering)
- `oninit` is called on creation, immediately before rendering. It is called once and only once for any Ractive instance, whether or not it gets rendered. It's therefore a good place to set up event handlers etc. The opposite of `oninit` is `onteardown`, so you can use that handler to do any cleanup if necessary (or use `this.on('teardown'...)` inside `oninit`).
- `onrender` is called whenever a component is rendered. This could happen more than once (if you unrendered, then re-rendered, etc) or not at all. If you need to store DOM references etc, this is the place. The opposite of `onrender` is `onunrender`.

I did a [fork of your codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNXbjp?editors=101), replacing the jQuery stuff with more idiomatic Ractive code to show how you'd do it without storing DOM references.

Comment: Hmm, you're right about `this.find` I'm trying to reproduce the issue I was having and I can't seem to. I think I was using the latest version when I ran into the issue. Does the `cdn.ractivejs.org/latest` point to 0.7.2 or a more up to date version? If it's a more up to date version it might have been fixed already (if there was ever an issue). Thank you for the fork. This helps tremendously. I'll look through the docs and create a list of examples that I saw using the old `init` api in a github issue.

Comment: No probs! Latest is 0.7.2 - you can always see the version at the top of the .js file in a comment block, or by logging `Ractive.VERSION`

Comment: FYI: `oninit` behaves different from the explanation: https://jsfiddle.net/ceremcem/ruv3nw8u/1/